# Set IFS for for loop within subshell

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
IFS='\n'
for i in "$(IFS='\n' printf 'abc\nxyz\n123 456\n')"; do
    echo "????"
    echo "$i"
done

echo "output"
echo "${args[@]}"
```

The following outputs:

```
????
abc
xyz
123 456
output
```

How can I get the for loop to iterate for each line? Why is the `IFS='\n'` command not making it behave in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double quotes make the "command substitution" one single argument. Try without:

```
$ for i in $( printf 'abc\nxyz\n123 456\n'); do   echo "????";   echo "$i"; done
????
abc
????
xyz
????
123 456
```

Plus, your `IFS` is set to a string containing the two chars "\" and "n". In e.g. `bash`, you might want to try `$'\n'`.